# How do I start a new while loop from a new file -- Python 3 (Using Pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, pygame

I have a while loop running my game on one file, example.py:

```
import pygame

while test == True:

    if key[pygame.K_e]:
        test = False
```

On my next file, I create

```
from example import *

testloop = True

while testloop == True:
    print("test")
```

Once the screen shows up for the new file, the while loop cancels. If statements seem to fail. How can I start another loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a loop inside a loop:

```
    while True:
        do something
        while i < 10:
            do something else
```

If you want multiple loops to be executing "at the same time", look into Python's `threading` and/or `multiprocessing` libraries.

Note that when you `import` a Python module, you are not necessarily executing it as you would expect. You can call methods or create objects from the module you import, though.